# Why following test doesn't pass?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, konacha

I've the following EmberJS/Konacha code. Does anyone have a clue why test doesn't pass ?

EDIT:

I've added test case which tests the attribute value instead of the reference.

```
#= require ../spec_helper

describe "Zaptax.v2014.App.AnswersLookup", ->
  beforeEach( ->
    Test.store = TestUtil.lookupStore()
  )

  it 'finds the answer by reference', ->
    page = Test.store.push Zaptax.v2014.App.PageModel, {id: 666, sequence: 123}

    assert.equal Test.store.find('page', 666).get('sequence'), 123
```

Returns:

```
Failed: Zaptax.v2014.App.AnswersLookup finds the answer by reference
  AssertionError: expected undefined to equal 123
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell but it looks as if you're trying to test the equality of two objects - this will always return false.

Comment: Where do you think I can look for any clues ?

Comment: `Test.store.find...` should at least return the `PageModel` instance but it returns blank `Object ()`

Comment: @LeszekA Do not forget that `find` is asynchronous and returns a promise object.

Comment: I use localstorage as adapter

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you're trying to test the equality of two objects - this will always return false. For example:

```
var a = {};
var b = {};
assert(a === b); // false
```

What you'll probably need to do is check that the *values* of the properties on the objects are equal with a series of assertions instead.

```
var a = { name: 'Bob' };
var b = { name: 'Bob' };
assert(a.name === b.name); // true
```

Comment: I've another test case following your tips but the issue is that store doesn't contain the model instance.